# Mapping Using Ebean in Play Framework

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have to run queries **(SELECT/INSERT)** in MySQL database using Ebean.
There are two options that I found in Java - Play framework

```
1. Connection conn=DB.getConnection();
   Statement st=conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from table1");
```

Using Ebean

```
 2.Connection conn=DB.getConnection();
    SqlUpdate down=Ebean.createSqlUpdate("insert into table1 (codefile,ADT,AD,TAG) VALUES (7555,'Ebean',0,0)");
    down.execute();
```

But I want to **Map** (insert complete array) in MySQL database rather than using the queries above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as poornerd suggested - you need to create models first with proper fields, then create and object, pseudo code :

```
MyModel obj = new MyModel();
obj.codefile = 7555;
obj.adt = "Ebean";
obj.ad = 0;
obj.tag = 0;
obj.save()
```

(of course you can create proper `constructors` in model(s) as well to shortcut it to:

```
MyModel obj = new MyModel(7555, "Ebean", 0, 0);
obj.save()
```

Take a closer look to models of [computer-database](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.1.x/samples/java/computer-database) sample app

Note.: sample you found *`SqlUpdate down=Ebean.createSqlUpdate...`* was a demo where it was required to perform 'manual' query, but for common use cases you should go with common Ebean approach...